# Copy-Paste in xfce4-terminal adds 0~ and 1~

Tags: xfce4-terminal

I use xubuntu 14.04, 64 bit. Every now and then, when I try to paste some text in xfce4-terminal, instead of the expected text to be pasted, it is surrounded by `0~` and `1~`, such as:

```
0~mvn clean install1~
```

The text is supposed to be `mvn clean install` -- I verified this by pasting the content in various other applications (gnome-terminal, gedit and others). Every application pastes correctly the content, except xfce4-terminal. I couldn't find any references for this on the internet (unfortunately, it is hard to search for text with special characters on google.com...). Why does this happen?

Comment: How are you pasting? Middle click, or something else?

Comment: I've tried every method: middle click, right click and chose option paste, ctrl+shift+v. When the 0~ and 1~ characters appear, it does not matter which pasting method I use.

Answer (score 240, accepted):

The issue is that your terminal is in bracketed paste mode, but doesn’t seem to support it properly. The issue was fixed in VTE, but xfce4-terminal is still using an old and unmaintained version of it.

You can try temporarily turning bracketed paste mode off by using:

```
printf "\e[?2004l"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will test this as soon as the issue reproduces (it may take a day or two)

Comment: If you can’t always reproduce it it might be that you were running some program that enabled bracketed paste mode and then it crashed, thus wasn’t able to disable it before exiting.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I've been struggling with this issue for more than a year. Is it possible to disable this "bracketed paste mode" completely? BTW, who implements such crazy things? ;)

Comment: it depends on your terminal.  And it is a really useful feature, since it lets applications know whether something was typed in or pasted.  For one, weechat, an IRC program, uses it to ask if you want to send multi-line pastes, which it couldn't do without bracketed paste mode, since then there would be no way to know if the user typed the lines or not.

Comment: How can I find which program is messing with bracketed paste mode?

Comment: For distributions based on Ubuntu you can try to install patched version of 'vte' package from https://launchpad.net/~adrozdoff/+archive/ubuntu/vte

Comment: Great solution, but when I tried to run `0~printf "\e[?2004l"1~`, it told me `-bash: 0~printf: command not found`. ;)

Comment: @CynicallyNaive You need to disable bracketed paste mode to copy and paste the printf command correctly. Before that, it will surely add those annoying 0~ and 1~ in the pasted text.

Comment: I definitely encounter this ( undesired ) behavior, at least in  `XTerm 322`
  when I have a remote .. i.e. `ssh` process running, and I have "escaped" back to the parent shell.  So the "remote" session has no such problem, but every time I escape to the "local" session it now exhibits the *bracketed paste* behavior ( whenever I paste from the clipboard ).  I tried the `printf "\e[?2004l"` from  *remmy*, above and that is working nicely !  Thanks.

Comment: BTW - ( adding to my last comment ) every time I resume my remote shell, and escape back to local again ... the bracketed mode behavior comes back.

Answer (score 144):

My issue was due to a badly-closed bash session. So running command `reset` in my terminal solved it immediately.

Comment: For me, this does not work.  `printf "\e[?2004l"` works. Terminal: zoc terminal, system: CentOS.

Comment: This problem happened to me inside of a `tmux` session. I had to detach from `tmux` first (CTRL+B D) and run `reset` from the regular session. This fixed the problem even in the `tmux` session.

Answer (score 33):

I had the same issue, it occurs after I use vi.

Mine was resolved by adding `set t_BE=`  to my `.vimrc` file.

For [reference](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/term.txt.html#xterm-bracketed-paste), this is what t_BE does:

> t_BE    enable bracketed paste mode

Answer (score 12):

This behavior occurs when the terminal emulator is stuck in [bracketed paste mode](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Bracketed-Paste-Mode).

This typically happens when an application exits uncleanly (crashes or is buggy).

Another reason for the phenomenon to occur frequently is a [bug in older versions of VTE](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vte/+bug/1506166) (VTE is the terminal emulation widget under `gnome-terminal` and `xfce4-terminal` and many more) which is triggered by certain actions in certain utilities such as [toggling the panels in Midnight Commander](https://midnight-commander.org/ticket/3207).

To see if this bug is fixed in the VTE-based terminal emulator you're running: Execute `echo -ne '\e[>c'`, this will insert a few characters as if you typed them. If the middle number is `3602` or bigger, the aforementioned old VTE bug is no longer present for you. If the number is smaller than that, VTE is still affected and gets stuck in bracketed paste mode more often than it should.

To see if a certain terminal emulator is fixed in a certain Ubuntu distribution, check its dependencies on [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/). `libvte-2.91-0` is good. `libvte-2.90-9` is only good if the actual version of that package is 0.36.2 or newer, and `libvte9` is bad. In particular, `xfce4-terminal` is buggy in Xenial, and fixed in Zesty.

Answer (score 1):

This may not apply directly to your problem, but I found this symptom to probably, in my case, be caused by my editor-of-choice 'mcedit' (Midnight Commander)

To alleviate the bug problem, I added the following function to my .bashrc file:

```
### vvv 'function mcedit' is a fix-up for the ~0/~1 paste problem
function mcedit() { command mcedit $@ ; printf '\e[?2004l' ; }
```

Then 'source .bashrc'

Now every time I execute 'mcedit', it automatically adds the 'printf "\e[?2004l"' when I close out to reset the "Bracketed Paste Mode"

Works for me, YMMV.

The same approach can be used with vi, vim, nano, or any other misbehaving program.

Answer (score 0):

There is an additional way that this problem can manifest. Readline's `.inputrc` file can contain the following:

```
set enable-bracketed-paste On
```

This is not fixed by any of the above methods and has eluded me for months. Removing this line or setting

```
set enable-bracketed-paste Off
```

will fix this nicely.